# How to show first equality in this equation?

Tags: calculus, analysis

The equation is:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{0}^{h} f(t)\,\mathrm dt = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dh}\left(\int_{0}^{h} f(t)\,\mathrm dt\right)\bigg|_{h=0}=f(0)$$

I saw it in a proof of "continuous vector field $\;\mathbf v:U\to\Bbb R^n$ is a gradient field iff it is conservative" where $f(t)$ was a component of a vector field evaluated at a point $r(t)$ so I have just changed it to $f(t)$ in my question as it is really the analysis I am stuck with. I understand the second equality is just the fundamental theorem of calculus which is straightforward but I don't understand how you get from the first expression to the second. I have tried by definition of derivative and also using FToC but can't get it to work.

Comment: $\frac{1}{h}\left(\int_0^h f(t) dt\right) = \frac{\int_0^h f(t) dt - \int_0^0 f(t) dt}{h}$

Comment: The first equality is the *definition* of the derivative at $0$.